# double.Parse not working on DataGridView Cell Value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've got a `DataGridView` that I'd like to apply formatting changes to based on cell values.  I'd like to do it using the original `DataTable` source but unfortunately building the source required removing and reorienting certain rows so the indexes are off.  As such, I'm trying to do it using

```
 double.TryParse(DataGridView
                .Rows[index]
                .Cells["ColumnName"]
                .FormattedValue.ToString(), out dbl);
```

however, it never recognizes the value as a double.  I've verified the output using MessageBox'es and that there are no leading or trailing spaces that might cause issue by adding "-" to both sides of the MessageBox string.  I'm clueless as to why it will always regard the value as not a double even on values that are clearly parseable as doubles.

Edit : I'm not sure what changed over the weekend but I came in, fixed a different bug unrelated to this and now the bold is working using .Value rather than .FormattedValue as suggested by gh0st below.

Comment: Can you show an examle of what it should work in your opinion?

Comment: Any reason why you're using `FormattedValue` rather than `Value`?

Comment: And why you're using `DataGridView.Rows` instead of `theDataGrid.Rows`? Or is that just for the sake of example?

Comment: We'll also remain pretty clueless unless you show us the value you're trying to parse as a double.

Comment: In Winforms, if you want to "_apply formatting changes based on cell values_", use the DataGridView.CellFormatting event.

Comment: MSDN: `FormattedValue: Gets the value of the cell as formatted for display.` Therefore it can have characters that can't be parsed by `double.TryParse`. Try `Convert.ToDouble`

Comment: I changed to Value-I was using FormattedValue because I didn't know just Value existed (learning as I go).  The code still is not noticing the double values-the specific values in the current example are 1.1 and 1.2.  The DataGridView is named, but I just used DataGridView as an example.

Comment: If column type is double, then _double d=(double)dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells.Value;_

Answer (score 0):

`double.TryParse()` will parse the string in a culture dependant way.  It is very likely that your current culture expects the decimal point to be some other symbol, like the comma or something.

For instance, on my machine, I can force it to fail the parsing by passing a different culture, like this:

```
double.TryParse("1.2", 
                NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, 
                CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"), 
                out dbl); // returns false
```

If this is what is happening to you, then either you find a way to change the current culture, or perhaps you can do the parsing this way instead to ensure consistent results:

```
double.TryParse("1.2", 
                NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, 
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                out dbl); // returns true
```

(*) Note: the `NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands` values can be adjusted as you like. I just set it to that in this example, because that is the default that the `TryParse` method uses when using the overload with less parameters.

Comment: I actually checked my culture to be sure because I saw that that could cause issues.  But thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. So I'm understanding that you are still unable to parse the double?  If I was in your position, here is what I would do: I would print out the ascii value of every character of the string returned by `.FormattedValue.ToString()` to see if there isn't any funny character that slipped in there, maybe even some invisible character.  Feel free to post back with that information to see if we can assist you further. Good luck.

Comment: Oh no, it's working now.  I made sure there weren't any sneaky characters previously.  I changed from .FormattedValue to .Value last week and it wasn't working.  I came in this week and it was suddenly working.  All I can think of is I was running on an older copy somehow (I sometimes have the same project open in multiple VS windows).  Thanks again for the help.